# Can I simplify this Javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I may have gone around the most convoluted way to achieve this (see code below). Could someone with experience tell me if there is a better way?

I have two JSON objects `resource` and `data`. I want to loop over each new item in `data` and if the key matches in `resource` replace the value for that key in resource with the value in data. If this does not make sense the code I have below will.

This works and does what I need it to do, but it does not feel right (don't laugh)

```
factory.put = function (resource, data) {
        dataArr = [data];
        resourceArr = [resource];


        for (var i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
            var obj = dataArr[i];
            for (var key in obj) {
                var attrName = key;
                var attrValue = obj[key];


                for (var i = 0; i < resourceArr.length; i++) {
                    var obj = resourceArr[i];
                    for (var key in obj) {
                        var resourceArrName = key;
                        var resourceArrValue = obj[key];

                        if (resourceArrName == attrName){
                           resource[resourceArrName] = attrValue
                        }
                    }

                    }

                }
            }

           resource.put()
        }
```

Comment: "This works and does what I need to do" > then post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are you putting `data` and `resource` into arrays?

Comment: @forgivenson I could only get my loop to iterate over if they were arrays. I did try dataArr[0][i] but that did not work.

Comment: @Stéphane Bruckert is codereview better then for this sort of question? The code above does have lots of problems tho.

Comment: @Spike I'm not sure why you feel the need to loop through an array of objects, when you just have two objects, `data` and `resource`. See my answer and let me know if that doesn't work and I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you have no need to stuff the objects into arrays. You just loop through the attributes of one object, `data`, check if that attribute exists in the other object, `resource`, and if it does, replace the value in `resource` with that of `data`.

```
for (var key in data) {
    var attrName = key;
    var attrValue = data[key];

    if(resource[attrName]) {
        resource[attrName] = attrValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate over resourceArr's keys. Just check if resourceArr[key] exists, if so, set the value.

Something like:

```
if(resourceArr[key])
 resourceArr[key] = attrValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to simplify the loops, is to use the [forEach](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/docs/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) function, which angular provides:

```
factory.put = function (resource, data) {
    dataArr = [data];
    resourceArr = [resource];

    angular.forEach(dataArr, function(obj) {
        angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
            angular.forEach(resourceArr, function(resourceObj) {
                if(resourceObj[key]) {
                    resourceObj[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    resource.put()
}
```